# TCP connection end of file in 660 seconds

Tags: sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to connect to an IRC channel using boost::asio. I am able to connect and communicate with the server for 660 seconds, but at that mark the connection is always closed with an end of file error.

Where should I be looking to solve this? My code? My connection?

Comment: Can you try a different IRC server?  If you do and it still happens there, that suggests the error is on your side; if the problem only happens with a particular IRC server, that suggests the behavior is coming from something unique to that server.

Comment: Do you receive data from the server during that 660s? Maybe you don't respond to a PING message?

Comment: I do receive all the data from the server, but I don't think I got a ping message. For now, I am just reconnecting whenever I detect the connection is closed. I will investigate the ping further later. Thanks for your help!